# Can a low concentration of an acid disolve solids just as well?

Tags: acid-base

I'm in the process of removing some hard water stains with vinegar.  It's not working so well.

The stains are in a large fish tank, which I have filled with water and vinegar.  I would expect a lower concentration of acetic acid to cause the acid to dissolve the calcified material slower, but it doesn't seem to be having any effect.

Is there a threshold-like effect on an acid's ability to dissolve such solids, such that a lower concentration would simply be unable to dissolve them (rather than merely dissolving them slower)?

Answer (score 2):

The rate of dissolution depends on $\mathrm{pH}$ and $\mathrm{pH}$ dependent equilibrium reaction chain :

$$\begin{align}
\ce{2 CH3COOH + CaCO3 v &<=> (CH3COO)2Ca + Ca(HCO3)2}\\
\ce{2 CH3COOH + Ca(HCO3)2 &<=> (CH3COO)2Ca + 2 H2CO3}\\
\ce{H2CO3 &<=>   H2O + CO2(aq)}\\
\ce{CO2(aq) &<=>   CO2(g)}\\
\end{align}$$

what can be written in the equivalent ionic form:

$$\begin{align}
\ce{CaCO3 v &<=> Ca^2+ + CO3^2-}\\
\ce{CH3COOH &<=> CH3COO-  + H+}\\
\ce{H+ + CO3^2- &<=> HCO3-}\\
\ce{HCO3-  + H+ &<=> H2CO3}\\
\ce{H2CO3 &<=>   H2O + CO2(aq)}\\
\ce{CO2(aq) &<=>   CO2(g)}\\
\end{align}$$

6% vinegar (1M) acetic acid has $\mathrm{pH=p}K_{\mathrm{a}}/2=2.37$.

Vinegar with 1/11 acid  spent has pH 3.75, with activity of $\ce{H2O+}$  24 times lower, so does is lower the reaction speed.

Vinegar with the acid half spent has pH 4.75, with activity of $\ce{H2O+}$ 240 times lower.

Vinegar with 10/11 acid  spent has pH 5.75, with activity of $\ce{H2O+}$  2400 times lower.

If pH raises enough, equilibrium concentration of $\ce{CO2(aq)}$ does not cross the gas solubility limit anymore and reaction approaches equilibrium, as production of gaseous carbon dioxide ceases..

If initial concentration crosses some minimal threshold, $\mathrm{pH}$ raises to level not able to produce gaseous carbon dioxide before water gets saturated by $\ce{CO2}$.

Some carbonate gets dissolved as bicarbonate, but with low initial acetic acid concentration, this dissolution is slow.

See also [carbonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid?wprov=sfla1) Wikipedia article.

Another effect is diffusion limitation. Without stirring, the acid near walls may get spent, while the acid abundance in free volume is intact, without access to limescale. Rate of acid diffusion to walls limits rate of dissolution.

Personally I would suggest rather [citric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid?wprov=sfla1), that have much higher acidity.

And/or, instead of filling the whole volume by diluted solution , rather using wall washing by concentrated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your stain, you might want to consider a soap as well. As for your more theoretical question, yes there is a threshold. If the concentration of acetic acid is high enough, it will be less effective. However, it would have to be very high. This is described by Le Chatelier's principle